# Different Behavior in the Browser and in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

when executing this javascript code

```js
let bar = 'bar';
function foo() {
  return bar;
}
console.log(foo());
bar = 'baz';
```

in the browser it logs `baz` and in node.js it logs `bar`, why does that happen ?
and wouldn't `bar` be more intuitive at this point ?

Comment: How are you testing it in the browser? In the snippet editor or in a real script (or the JSFiddle at least)?

Comment: For me both the browser (chrome v117) and node (v18.17) both output `baz`, [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) however log `bar`

Comment: oh, I see what's happening, it is logging bar, and then showing baz if you run it in the console, because when you run something in the console, the output is the result of the last statement (hence the left arrow before baz) - if you don't see bar logged in the console before baz, you're using the console wrong

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me that you run this code in the browser's dev tools. In that case, you should (and I'm pretty confident you actually do) first see `bar` as the output of the `console.log(foo());` call. Then, after `bar`, you get `'baz'` as an additional line of output.

This additional `'baz'` comes from the last line of your code. The `bar = 'baz';` assignment does two things:

1. Assigns `'baz'` to the variable
2. Returns the right-hand side value of the assignment, which is `'baz'` in this case.

That's why you see this in the output.

If you paste the code in an actual script you won't see the additional output. See here:

```js
let bar = 'bar';
function foo() {
  return bar;
}
console.log(foo());
bar = 'baz';
```

It outputs only `bar`.

Answer (score 2):

Really an interesting question. But I think you may not have figured out who is the output in the console. When we execute code in the console, the browser always displays the return value of the last code. As this, `bar = 'baz'` return 'baz'(test it by `console.log(bar = 'baz')`) and it shows, the real output of `console.log(foo());` comes before this.[image]

If you are still confused about this, execute it:

```js
(() => {
  let bar = 'bar';
  function foo() {
    return bar;
  }
  console.log(foo());
  bar = 'baz';
})();
```